# Serilog child classes not logging when using ByIncludingOnly

Tags: serilog, serilog-sinks-file

I am using the following log configuration..

```
.WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<****.Application.Common.Services.Jobs.JobService>()).WriteTo.File("logs/jobs-.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
```

I am trying to make it so any classes the job service calls get logged.  I can't add those classes directly to the configuration because they are used from other classes with a high transaction volume, and I don't want to muddy the log.

Is there anyway to have children classes log from a the calling class that is configured?

Answer (score 2):

`Matching.FromSource<****.Application.Common.Services.Jobs.JobService>()` means that the `SourceContext` must be exactly `****.Application.Common.Services.Jobs.JobService` to match the filter.

If you want the filter to match anything under the `****.Application.Common.Services.Jobs` namespace then you need to apply a filter based on the namespace:

```
.WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc.Filter
    .ByIncludingOnly(
        Matching.FromSource(
            typeof(****.Application.Common.Services.Jobs.JobService).Namespace)
        )
    // ...
```

This filter will match any `SourceContext` that starts with `****.Application.Common.Services.Jobs`

---

NB: You also need to create the context logger to include the corresponding `SourceContext` property:

```
ILogger log = Log.ForContext<****.Application.Common.Services.Jobs.JobService>();
log.Information("...");
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the classes being called are in another namespace, or aren't necessary children of the namepsace name.

Comment: Your question says "children classes log from a the calling class" (sic) - classes that are not in the same namespace are _not_ "children classes". I don't think it's clear what your goal is.